# Why is Vercel throwing Module Not Found Error?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am making a website with Next.js and React. When I run it in development mode or build it its fine, but when I deploy it on Vercel it throws `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './data/navLinks' in '/vercel/path0/src'`. I have seen this question asked before, but all the answers I have seen were fixed by changing capitalization. However, it is still not working for me.

I deleted the navLinks file and implemented its code in another file, but then I started getting the error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/layout' in '/vercel/path0/src'` (this isn't even the file I moved the code into).

Here is part of the deployment message on vercel:

```
 WARN  Issues with peer dependencies found
.
├─┬ @babel/plugin-syntax-flow 7.18.6
│ └── ✕ missing peer @babel/core@^7.0.0-0
├─┬ @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx 7.19.0
│ ├── ✕ missing peer @babel/core@^7.0.0-0
│ └─┬ @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx 7.18.6
│   └── ✕ missing peer @babel/core@^7.0.0-0
└─┬ react-scripts 5.0.1
  └── ✕ unmet peer typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4": found 5.0.4
Peer dependencies that should be installed:
  @babel/core@">=7.0.0-0 <8.0.0"
Done in 15.5s
Running "pnpm run build"
> @ build /vercel/path0
> react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx update-browserslist-db@latest
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
Failed to compile.
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/layout' in '/vercel/path0/src'
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
Error: Command "pnpm run build" exited with 1
Deployment completed
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "pnpm run build" exited with 1
```

Comment: Had a similar issue. Happened because path names on vercel are case sensitive and locally - they ignored. Can you confirm your path to the files and files emselfs are identical (in terms of upper/lover cases)?

Comment: My IDE shows everything as lower case and I also ran the following commands just in case : git mv Components components;
cd components;
git mv Layout.tsx layout.tsx;
Also, all of my imports are the correct case.